# Payu money Payment GateWay Integration

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am trying to integrate payu money payment gateway in my app. 
Payumoney collect all information and done transaction and return back to my custom defined url webpage.

My problem is how to get the response code after successful transaction from payu money gateway?

```
int i = arc4random() % 9999999999;
NSString *strHash = [self createSHA512:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",i,[NSDate date]]];
NSString *txnid1 = [strHash substringToIndex:20];
NSLog(@"tnx1 id %@",txnid1);

//    NSString *key = @"JBZaLc";
//    NSString* salt = @"GQs7yium";

NSString *key = @"gtKFFx";
NSString* salt = @"eCwWELxi";

NSString *amount = dataMoney.usrAmount;
NSString *productInfo = @"App Products Info ";
NSString *firstname = dataMoney.usrName;
NSString *email = dataMoney.usrEmail;
NSString *phone = dataMoney.usrMobile;

NSString *surl = @"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dtnvwz5p4uymjvg/success.html";
NSString *furl = @"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/z69y7fupciqzr7x/furlWithParams.html";

NSString *hashValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||%@",key,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,salt];

NSString *hash = [self createSHA512:hashValue];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:txnid1,key,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,phone,surl,furl,hash, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txnid",@"key",@"amount",@"productinfo",@"firstname",@"email",@"phone",@"surl",@"furl",@"hash", nil]];

__block NSString *post = @"";
[parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([post isEqualToString:@""]) {
        post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",key,obj];
    }else{
        post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@=%@",post,key,obj];
    }

}];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://test.payu.in/_payment"]]];
// change URL for live
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[web_view_PayU loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: You should add some specific code and show what kind of problems you are running into with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define Merchant_Key @"your merchant key "
#define Salt @"your salt key"
#define Base_URL @"https://secure.payu.in"  

> //this base url  in case of origional  payment key's if you want to integarate with
 test key's write base Url can check in payumoney Faq 

** 
#define Success_URL @"https://www.google.co.in/"
#define Failure_URL @"http://www.bing.com/"
#define Product_Info @"Denim Jeans"
#define Paid_Amount @"1549.00"
#define Payee_Name @"Suraj Mirajkar"
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self setTitle:@"Make A Payment"];
    [self initPayment];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center;
    [activityIndicatorView setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
}

-(void)initPayment {
    int i = arc4random() % 9999999999;
    NSString *strHash = [self createSHA512:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",i,[NSDate date]]];// Generatehash512(rnd.ToString() + DateTime.Now);
    NSString *txnid1 = [strHash substringToIndex:20];
    strMIHPayID = txnid1;
    NSString *key = Merchant_Key;
  NSString *amount =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
              stringForKey:@"orderprice"];

    //NSString *amount = Paid_Amount;
    NSString *productInfo = Product_Info;
    NSString *firstname = Payee_Name;
   NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"suraj%d@yopmail.com",i];

//ADD A fake mail For Payment for testing purpose 


    // Generated a fake mail id for testing
    NSString *phone = @"9762159571";
    NSString *serviceprovider = @"payu_paisa";

    NSString *hashValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||%@",key,txnid1,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,Salt];
    NSString *hash = [self createSHA512:hashValue];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:txnid1,key,amount,productInfo,firstname,email,phone,Success_URL,Failure_URL,hash,serviceprovider
                                                                    , nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txnid",@"key",@"amount",@"productinfo",@"firstname",@"email",@"phone",@"surl",@"furl",@"hash",@"service_provider", nil]];
    NSLog(@"%@",parameters);
    __block NSString *post = @"";
    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([post isEqualToString:@""]) {
            post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",key,obj];
        } else {
            post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@=%@",post,key,obj];
        }
    }];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/_payment",Base_URL]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [_webviewPaymentPage loadRequest:request];
    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
}
-(NSString *)createSHA512:(NSString *)string {
    const char *cstr = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:string.length];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, (CC_LONG)data.length, digest);
    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString  stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    }
    return output;
}
#pragma UIWebView - Delegate Methods
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"WebView started loading");
}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    if (webView.isLoading) {
        return;
    }
    NSURL *requestURL = [[_webviewPaymentPage request] URL];
    NSLog(@"WebView finished loading with requestURL: %@",requestURL);
    NSString *getStringFromUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",requestURL];
    if ([self containsString:getStringFromUrl :Success_URL]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(delayedDidFinish:) withObject:getStringFromUrl afterDelay:0.0];
    } else if ([self containsString:getStringFromUrl :Failure_URL]) {
        // FAILURE ALERT
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry !!!" message:@"Your transaction failed. Please try again!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        alert.tag = 1;
        [alert show];
    }
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    NSURL *requestURL = [[_webviewPaymentPage request] URL];
    NSLog(@"WebView failed loading with requestURL: %@ with error: %@ & error code: %ld",requestURL, [error localizedDescription], (long)[error code]);
    if (error.code == -1009 || error.code == -1003 || error.code == -1001) { //error.code == -999
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops !!!" message:@"Please check your internet connection!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        alert.tag = 1;
        [alert show];
    }
}
- (void)delayedDidFinish:(NSString *)getStringFromUrl {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSMutableDictionary *mutDictTransactionDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:strMIHPayID forKey:@"Transaction_ID"];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:@"Success" forKey:@"Transaction_Status"];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:Payee_Name forKey:@"Payee_Name"];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:Product_Info forKey:@"Product_Info"];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:Paid_Amount forKey:@"Paid_Amount"];
        [self navigateToPaymentStatusScreen:mutDictTransactionDetails];
    });
}

#pragma UIAlertView - Delegate Method
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 0) {
        // Navigate to Payment Status Screen
        NSMutableDictionary *mutDictTransactionDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:Payee_Name forKey:@"Payee_Name"];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:Product_Info forKey:@"Product_Info"];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:Paid_Amount forKey:@"Paid_Amount"];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:strMIHPayID forKey:@"Transaction_ID"];
        [mutDictTransactionDetails setObject:@"Failed" forKey:@"Transaction_Status"];
        [self navigateToPaymentStatusScreen:mutDictTransactionDetails];
    }
}

- (BOOL)containsString: (NSString *)string : (NSString*)substring {
    return [string rangeOfString:substring].location != NSNotFound;
}

- (void)navigateToPaymentStatusScreen: (NSMutableDictionary *)mutDictTransactionDetails {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        PaymentStatusViewController *paymentStatusViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PaymentStatusScreenID"];
        paymentStatusViewController.mutDictTransactionDetails = mutDictTransactionDetails;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:paymentStatusViewController animated:YES];
    });
}


Important Note : you can check your Merchant key and Salt in seller Dashboard after Login ... Go To my account and check your merchant key and salt
```